# Many tutorials describe methods for adding multiple child view controllers in the Storyboard, why don't they just add multiple container views?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, interface-builder, uistoryboard

Many tutorials, [such as this one](http://sandmoose.com/post/35714028270/storyboards-with-custom-container-view-controllers) go over how to add multiple child view controllers via the Storyboard. But [this tutorial](http://thelongestblogurlicouldthinkof.blogspot.ca/2013/03/problem-i-needed-menu-that-slides-from.html) just adds multiple container views in the Storyboard.

Why is the first tutorial (and many others) going through such hoops to create multiple child view controllers if they could just use multiple view containers? Is this a new feature, or am I just misunderstanding what's going on?

Comment: The two tutorials that you link to are just different approaches, and the aim of the authors were different. There's nothing new about being able to add multiple container views (as opposed to just one -- I think container views themselves, came into use with iOS 6, but you could do it in code with the custom container controller api since iOS 5). You're free to pursue which ever approach (or one of your own) you prefer.

Comment: @rdelmar How do the aims of the authors differ?

Comment: In the first link, the author was interested in switching between two controllers whose views would occupy the one container view that he used. In the second, the author is using one container as his main view while sliding in and out another controller using another container. In any case, there is no answer to your broader question that isn't just opinion -- if you want to know why they did what they did, ask them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the other poster said, container views and embed segues were added in iOS 6. In iOS 5 adding child view controllers was more work since these options were not available.

Container views and embed segues only work with storyboards. Some developers don't like and don't use storyboards. In that case you would have to set up your child view controllers yourself.

I think container views and embed segues are wonderful, and make setting things up much easier. By all means use them. They do most/all of the housekeeping for you.

Comment: But it seems like in the first tutorial container views are available. Why don't they just use multiple instead of the ugly work around?

Comment: I completely agree it's ridiculous they don't have a multiple concept inside a container view area.  It's completely silly having to have a pile of container views, all the same size, and choosing one!